# В iOS11 titleView у UINavigationItem отображается некорректно

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Есть у меня в приложении на Swift 3.3 один `UIViewController`, в котором мне нужно установить нестандартный заголовок. До iOS11 я делал это так (привожу не весь код, а лишь ключевые моменты):

```
class MyController : UIViewController {

    private lazy var customTitleView : UIImageView = {

        $0.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:10, height:10)
        $0.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        $0.clipsToBounds = true
        return $0
    }(UIImageView(image:UIImage(named:"my_image")))

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationItem.titleView = self.customTitleView
    }
}
```

Раньше благодаря данному коду заголовок у `self.navigationItem` был всегда по центру и изображение сохраняло указанный мной в инициализаторе размер. Теперь в iOS11 данный заголовок растягивается по всей высоте, заданные мною размеры игнорируются. Как мне вернуть прежнее поведение программы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге я решил сделать следующее: завернуть картинку-логотип, которую я показывал в `titleView`, в объект класса-наследника `UIView`, и уже в этом объекте настраивать размер картинки как дочернего элемента. В итоге получилось что-то наподобие следующего:

```
class LogoView : UIView {

    private static let rootImageTopOffset : CGFloat = 10.0 // отступ сверху для изображения
    private static let rootImageBottomOffset : CGFloat = 5.0 // отступ снизу для изображения

    //Изображение, ради которого всё и затевалось
    private lazy var rootImageView : UIImageView = {

        $0.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        $0.clipsToBounds = true
        return $0
    }(UIImageView(image:UIImage(named:"my_image")))

    override init(frame: CGRect) {

        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupSubviews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupSubviews()
    }

    private func setupSubviews() {

        self.addSubview(self.rootImageView)
    }   

    //Функцию setupFrame я вызываю, когда мне нужно поменять размеры картинки (например, после поворота экрана)
    final func setupFrame(rootFrame:CGRect) {

        self.frame = rootFrame
        self.rootImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: LogoView.rootImageTopOffset, width: rootFrame.size.width, height: rootFrame.size.height - LogoView.rootImageTopOffset - LogoView.rootImageBottomOffset)
    }     
}
```

После этого я использую объект класса `LogoView` в качестве `titleView` у моего `UINavigationItem`. Ни в коем случае не утверждаю, что данное решение является самым лучшим, но на скорую руку ничего получше придумать я не смог.